# rename using a lookup csv file

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to read in a directory of files and then search for the file in a CSV file with two columns name,newname. I would like to lookup the file and then rename the original file with newname.  Sometimes my original file will be missing from the CSV list.

```
$folder = "c:\test\"
$csv    = "C:\tests\replace.csv" 

$keywords = @{}
Import-Csv $csv | ForEach-Object {
  $keywords[$_.Search] = $_.Replace
}
Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  $newname = $_.Name
  foreach ($word in $keywords.Keys) {
    $newname = $newname.Replace($word, $keywords[$word])
  }

  if ($_.Name -ne $newname) {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
  }
}
```

It does work for some files it then renames 1 file a long long string based on the newname field.  any help would be great.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data in the CSV file? I think you may be over complicating this.

Comment: If the csv file contains the complete current name as key you don't need to iterate all keys, just use the current name as key. Also `Rename-Item is smart enough to not try to rename to the same name.

Comment: IN my csv file i have two columns, search,newname and it is delimited by a comma. the contents are something like file1111.dat,newfilename.dat

Answer (score 0):

As LotPings already said: since you already created your *lookup-hashtable* you don't need to iterate over it for each item - just pass the filename as the key like so:

```
# replace this with your Import-Csv later
$csv_data = "Search,Replace
old_file.txt,new_file.txt
old_file2.csv,new_file2.csv
"

$folder = ".\testfiles"

$keywords = @{ }
$replace_data = $csv_data | ConvertFrom-Csv # replace this with your Import-Csv later

$replace_data | ForEach-Object {
    $keywords[$_.Search] = $_.Replace
}

Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $file_name = $_.Name

    # skip files that are not listed in your csv
    if ($keywords."$file_name") {
        Rename-Item $_.FullName $keywords."$file_name"
    }
}
```